i get this error i think the problem that the methode return an object and i'm using *ngfor to browse it
ERROR RuntimeError: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Blob]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe? Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG02200%60
`
`static readonly GetEmployeesPath = '/Employe/getEmployesInfoBase';/**



This method provides access to the full HttpResponse, allowing access to response headers.



To access only the response body, use getEmployees() instead.







This method doesn't expect any request body.*/getEmployees$Response(params?: GetEmployees$Params, context?: HttpContext): Observable<StrictHttpResponse<Array<EmployeBaseInformation>>> {return getEmployees(this.http, this.rootUrl, params, context);}



/**



This method provides access only to the response body.



To access the full response (for headers, for example), getEmployees$Response() instead.







This method doesn't expect any request body.*/getEmployees(params?: GetEmployees$Params, context?: HttpContext): Observable<Array<EmployeBaseInformation>> {return this.getEmployees$Response(params, context).pipe(map((r: StrictHttpResponse<Array<EmployeBaseInformation>>): Array<EmployeBaseInformation> => r.body));}'

`



`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeesControllerService } from '../../../../services/services';
import { EmployeBaseInformation } from '../../../../services/models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employe-list',
  templateUrl: './employe-list.component.html',
  styleUrl: './employe-list.component.css'
})
export class EmployeListComponent implements OnInit{
  employes$: Observable<EmployeBaseInformation[]>=new Observable<EmployeBaseInformation[]>();;

  constructor(private employeService: EmployeesControllerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employes$ = this.employeService.getEmployees();
  }

}`
`
`
`

`<table>
  Nom
  Prénom
  Matricule
  Département
  Fonction




  {{ employe.nom }}
  {{ employe.prenom }}
  {{ employe.matricule }}
  {{ employe.departement?.nom }}
  {{ employe.fonction?.nom }}

```
i want to display a list of employees but i get this error please any help?

what does this return this.employeService.getEmployees(); ? there is not much information provided to help with, please try adding full info ... How to ask a good question
